# Update Records with Flow Identifier Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a script together to update the ActionTypeID column based off the particular Area flow for each Visit ID.

There are three Areas, and a Visit can move between any of the areas and I need to update an ActionTypeID column based off the 5 values in the ActionType table.

The logic for updating is all based off the Area column for each VisitID record where you can see VisitID 100 moves from Area 1 to 2 to 3. While VisitID record 101 moves from Area 1 to 2 and then back to 1 and forward to 2, and then 3. Please see the column "WhatActionTypeShouldBe".

What's a good way to update this column for what will be may millions of rows, and all sorts of movement records across the areas?

[image]

Sample Data

```
Create Table #SampleData
(
    VisitID int,
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime,
    Area tinyint,
    ActionTypeID tinyint,
    WhatActionTypeShouldBe tinyint
)
insert into #SampleData
(
    VisitID,
    StartDate,
    EndDate,
    Area,
    ActionTypeID,
    WhatActionTypeShouldBe
)
select
    100,
    '2020-01-26 00:16:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:18:09.800',
    1,
    0,
    1
union 
select
    100,
    '2020-01-26 00:18:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:21:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    2
union
select
    100,
    '2020-01-26 00:21:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    3,
    0,
    3
union
select
    101,
    '2020-01-26 00:16:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:18:09.800',
    1,
    0,
    1
union 
select
    101,
    '2020-01-26 00:18:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:21:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    2
union
select
    101,
    '2020-01-26 00:21:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:24:09.800',
    1,
    0,
    4
union
select
    101,
    '2020-01-26 00:24:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    2
union
select
    101,
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:30:09.800',
    3,
    0,
    3
union
select
    102,
    '2020-01-26 00:24:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    2
union
select
    102,
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:30:09.800',
    3,
    0,
    3
union
select
    103,
    '2020-01-26 00:24:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    1,
    0,
    1
union
select
    103,
    '2020-01-26 00:27:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:30:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    2
union
select
    103,
    '2020-01-26 00:30:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:34:09.800',
    3,
    0,
    3
union
select
    103,
    '2020-01-26 00:34:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:36:09.800',
    2,
    0,
    5
union
select
    103,
    '2020-01-26 00:36:09.800',
    '2020-01-26 00:37:09.800',
    3,
    0,
    3

Create Table #ActionType
(
    ActionTypeID tinyint,
    ActionTypeName varchar(50)
)

insert into #ActionType
(
    ActionTypeID,
    ActionTypeName
)
select
    1,
    'Visit Started'
union
select
    2,
    'Progress to Area 2'
union
select
    3,
    'Complete Visit in Area 3'
union
select
    4,
    'Return to Area 1'
union
select
    5,
    'Return to Area 2'

select * from #SampleData

select * from #ActionType

drop table #SampleData
drop table #ActionType
```

Comment: Please explain the logic for calculating the new column.

Comment: Apologies for it obviously not being 100% clear @GordonLinoff - have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something with `lag()` and other window functions.  It is a little tricky, but something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select sd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by visitid, area order by startdate) as seqnum
      from #sampledata sd
     )
update toupdate
    set actiontypeid = (case when area = 1 and seqnum = 1 then 1
                             when area = 2 and seqnum = 1 then 2
                             when area = 3 then 3
                             when area = 1 then 4
                             when area = 2 then 5
                        end);
```

The logic for "5" is quite unclear.  However, something like this seems to be what you need.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that does the trick. I've updated the original question regarding logic 5 - could you please modify?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach that tracks where the visitor has been to update `ActionTypeID`:

```
WITH Actions AS (
  SELECT SampleData.*,
         LAG(AREA, 1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID ORDER BY StartDate) AS Last_Area,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN Area = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY VisitID ORDER BY StartDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS Area_1_Visits
  FROM SampleData
)
UPDATE Actions
  SET ActionTypeID =
       CASE WHEN Area = 1 AND Area_1_Visits = 0 THEN 1
            WHEN Area = 1 AND Area_1_Visits > 0 THEN 4
            WHEN Area = 2 AND Last_Area = 1     THEN 2
            WHEN Area = 2 AND Last_Area = 3     THEN 5
            WHEN Area = 3 THEN 3 
       END
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/555e3/2)